# What's the best way to calculate survival time using outputs from random survival forest

Tags: survival, random-forest

I have built a random survival forest using R package randomForestSRC. The OOB error rate is around 10%.  I was wondering whether anyone had some experience in utilizing the outputs from this model for producing the "predicted future survival time"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, the authors of the randomForestSRC package have published a couple of articles on the subject that you may find useful for developing predicted survival curves.

For example, in this [article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v50/i11/paper), the authors provide some R code used to "predict" survival curves for a new set of data that they created on 3 made-up individuals to assess the "accuracy" of predicted survival curves.

On a side note, I have been unsuccessful in finding much literature on the use of random forests for survival curve prediction; hence, I am wary about applying such modeling to real-world applications - especially, since it is a paradigm shift from inferential to predictive application.